# Mootools: Datepicker: invertAvailable with minDate is not working

Tags: datepicker, mootools

I am using datepicker from mootools and I need to disable specific dates.

This is the code:

```
<script>
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
new Picker.Date(
$$('#ctrl_25'),{
'draggable':'false',
'pickerClass':'datepicker_bootstrap',
'useFadeInOut':'!Browser.ie',
'startDay':1,'titleFormat':'%d. %B %Y',
'availableDates':{2015: {5: [1,14]}},
'invertAvailable':'true',
'minDate':new Date(2015,3,24),
'toggle':$$('#toggle_25'),
'togglesOnly':false,
'positionOffset':{x:-197,y:-182},
'format':'%d.%m.%Y'});
});
</script>
```

now the problem here is that 'minDate' is not working if I am using 'invertAvailable' all days before that minDate are also clickable.

Is there any workaround?